# Int value resets in for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

I wrote a web scraping script in python2.7. There are in total 4486 pages. I have to extract Titles from each one of them. I am using beautifulSoup. I ran a for loop to increment the page numbers as the url has page increments.

Each page has 50 entries. However when my total entries are 12850, my python program stops without any error.

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

string = 'https://marketpublishers.com/members/dummyurl/info.html?page='
for i in range(0,4487):
    myUrl = string+str(i)

    r = urllib.urlopen(myUrl).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')

    raw = soup.find_all("div", class_='listItemDef')
    file = open('testfile.txt','a')
    for element in raw:
        file.write(element.a.get_text())
        file.write('\n')
    file.close()
```

I assume that it has something to do with integer value cannot exceed 256. 
how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: First and foremost... why are you reopening the file on every iteration and closing it? Keep it open and then close or use a context manager.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. i will correct this.

Comment: Since when can integers in Python not exceed 256?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy. actually you are right, However I don't what is causing this

Comment: Use a debugger or some logging print statements to step through your loop and find the errors, since you've given a dummy URL.

Comment: Put some print statements in your code telling you where you are, the value of i, the value of r, etc. Almost certainly it will reveal something.